# How I can don't use |raw filter in the template for services

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a service, that generate and return simple html code of breadcrumb. But in template I always need to use `|raw` filter:

```
{{ $breadcrumb|raw }}
```

otherwise I can see escaped html code, not a real links:

```
<a href="/">Home</a> / <a href="/contacts">Contacts</a>
```

With `|raw` filter it's work well, but maybe I do something wrong and there are any other ways to do this without `|raw` filter? Or it's a normally to use raw filter in this case? I think there is more suitable solution, is't it? help me better understand it, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every argument passed to twig template is by default escaped. So it is normally that you need use `raw` filter. But if using `raw` filter is annoying for you, then you have two options.

**First - disable autoescaping (Not recommended):**

Turn autoescaping off globally by setting the `autoescape` option to `false` in `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    autoescape: false
```

**Second - Create twig extension (Recommended):**

Create twig extension with function which will render content and it be html safe.

```php
<?php

// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/BreadcrumbExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

class BreadcrumbExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $breadcrumbService;

    public function __construct(BreadcrumbService $breadcrumbService)
    {
        $this->breadcrumbService = $breadcrumbService;
    }

    /**
    * Returns a list of functions to add to the existing list.
    *
    * @return array An array of functions
    */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('acme_breadcrumbs', 
                array($this, 'renderBreadcrumbs'),
                array('is_safe' => array('html'))
            ),
        );
    }

    public function renderBreadcrumbs()
    {
        return $this->breadcrumbService->renderHtml();
    }  

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'breadcrumb_extension';
    }
}
```

Register service:

```
<service id="acme.breadcrumb.twig.extension" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\BreadcrumbExtension" public="false">
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
    <argument type="service" id="acme.breadcrumb.service" />
</service>
```

And now you can use it in twig template like this:

```
{{ acme_breadcrumbs() }}
```

Comment: Second case is very nice, I try it. Thanks!